# Complex structure with default values in Puppet

Tags: linux, puppet

Trying setup default values in an Array of Hashes in Puppet.
I am trying to configure urls to monitor.
It should contain:

- url
- name
- runbook
- comment[Optional]
- secure [default=true]
- warning [default=30]
- critical [default=15]

I got the following code:

```
puppet apply test.pp
```

test.pp:

```rb
class http_monitoring (
  Array[Struct[{
    url                 => String,
    name                => String,
    runbook             => String,
    Optional[comment]   => String,
    Optional[secure]    => Boolean,
    Optional[warning]   => Integer,
    Optional[critical]  => Integer,
  }]]
  $checks = [{
    secure   => true,
    warning  => 30,
    critical => 15,
  }]
){
  $checks.each | Hash $check | {
    notify {"${check}":}
  }
}

class website {
  class { 'http_monitoring':
    checks => [
      {url => 'https://example.com',  name => 'example'  ,runbook => 'https://link-to-docs.com/'},
      {url => 'https://example2.com', name => 'example2' ,runbook => 'https://link-to-docs.com/', warning => 5, critical => 10},
    ]
  }
}
include website
```

Results in:

```
Notice: {url => https://example.com, name => example, runbook => https://link-to-docs.com/}
Notice: /Stage[main]/Http_monitoring/Notify[{url => https://example.com, name => example, runbook => https://link-to-docs.com/}]/message: defined 'message' as '{url => https://example.com, name => example, runbook => https://link-to-docs.com/}'
Notice: {url => https://example2.com, name => example2, runbook => https://link-to-docs.com/, warning => 5, critical => 10}
Notice: /Stage[main]/Http_monitoring/Notify[{url => https://example2.com, name => example2, runbook => https://link-to-docs.com/, warning => 5, critical => 10}]/message: defined 'message' as '{url => https://example2.com, name => example2, runbook => https://link-to-docs.com/, warning => 5, critical => 10}'
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.01 seconds
```

The output I was hoping to get:

```
{url => 'https://example.com', name => example, runbook => https://link-to-docs.com/, secure => true, warning => 30, critical => 15}
{url => 'https://example2.com', name => 'example2', runbook => 'https://link-to-docs.com/', warning => 5, critical => 10, secure => true}
```

Running Puppet 6.12.0

Comment: The default value you are providing is used as the (whole) value for the parameter in the event that no other value is specified by any other means.  That's not what you want.  You're looking instead to *augment* the provided value, which you can do in the function body, but not in the parameter declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class http_monitoring (
  Array[Struct[{
    url                 => String,
    name                => String,
    runbook             => String,
    Optional[comment]   => String,
    Optional[secure]    => Boolean,
    Optional[warning]   => Integer,
    Optional[critical]  => Integer,
  }]]
  $checks = [{
    secure   => true,
    warning  => 30,
    critical => 15,
  }]
){
  $check_defaults = {
    secure   => true,
    warning  => 30,
    critical => 15,
  }

  # Checks with defaults
  $checks_with_defaults_added = $checks.map | Hash $next_check | {
    $check_defaults + $next_check
  }


  # $checks.each | Hash $check | {
  #   notify {"${check}":}
  # }

  $checks_with_defaults_added.each | Hash $check | {
    $check_output = String($check)
    notify { $check_output: }
  }
}

class website {
  class { 'http_monitoring':
    checks => [
      {url => 'https://example.com',  name => 'example'  ,runbook => 'https://link-to-docs.com/'},
      {url => 'https://example2.com', name => 'example2' ,runbook => 'https://link-to-docs.com/', warning => 5, critical => 10},
    ]
  }
}

include website
```